# stanford-nlp ner model with different classes than (Person,Organization,....)

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am currently in the quest for the construction of a Stanford NER model that will be able to recognize different classes than these builtin (Person, Organization, Location,....) in Stanford's models. For example, i would like to construct a NER model that will be trained to tag entities Hotel, Country, Owner.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can train an NER model for whatever classes you like.

Information about how to do this is here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml

You'll need to tag sentences with the classes you want.

This tool can be helpful for manually tagging sentences:

http://brat.nlplab.org